# $\mathrm{Hom}_A(\prod_i M_i, N) \cong \prod_i \mathrm{Hom}_A(M_i, N)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_A (M, \bigoplus_i N_i) \cong \prod_i \mathrm{Hom}_A(M, N_i)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum, direct-product

I am reading the notes of Pierre Shapira on Algebra and Geometry. He writes the following:
Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra, $M \in Mod(A)$. Then $\mathrm{Hom}_A(M, \prod_i N_i) \cong \prod_i \mathrm{Hom}_A(M, N_i)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_A (\bigoplus_i M_i, N) \cong \prod_i \mathrm{Hom}_A(M_i, N)$. I understand why these are true.

Nevertheless, I was wondering whether the other relations are true as well: $$\textstyle \mathrm{Hom}_A(\prod_i M_i, N) \cong \prod_i \mathrm{Hom}_A(M_i, N)$$
and
$$\textstyle \mathrm{Hom}_A (M, \bigoplus_i N_i) \cong \prod_i \mathrm{Hom}_A(M, N_i)$$
If the set of indices I is finite, of course it is because then the natural injection $\bigoplus_i M_i \to \prod_i M_i$ is a bijection (as the author writes on page 12). If not, I think that it is true as well, by the following proof:

For $\mathrm{Hom}_A(\prod_i M_i, N) \cong \prod_i \mathrm{Hom}_A(M_i, N)$: Define $\Phi: \mathrm{Hom}_A(\prod_i M_i, N) \to \prod_i \mathrm{Hom}_A(M_i, N)$, $(\phi: (m_1, \cdots, m_k) \mapsto n = \sum_i \alpha_i m_i)
 \to (\phi_1: m_1 \mapsto \alpha_i m_i, \cdots, \phi_N: m_k \mapsto \alpha_k m_k)$

This map is surjective, injective and k-linear.

The other one has a similar proof. Is the first statement and proof correct?

Comment: No. If you take $A$, $M$, $M_i$, $N$, $N_i$ all to be $\mathbb Z$ (considered as a ring or module, as appropriate), then one of the sides of each of your proposed isomorphisms is countable and the other side is uncountable. See https://mathoverflow.net/q/105771 to read about the first of the  isomorphisms.

Comment: Thank you for your response! What is then exactly wrong with the proposed isomorphism? Is it not surjective?

Comment: With all respect, your definition of $\Phi$ does not make sense. What do you mean with that definition? Have you really checked that this is a map at all? Do you know the definitions of direct product and direct sum? And what is $k$?

Answer (score 2):

No to both questions.

There is a natural homomorphism
$$\textstyle \alpha : \mathrm{Hom}_A(\prod_i M_i, N) \to \prod_i \mathrm{Hom}_A(M_i, N), \quad f \mapsto (f \circ \iota_i)_i,$$
but this has no reason to be injective or surjective. In fact, the right hand side is $\mathrm{Hom}_A(\bigoplus_i M_i,N)$, so $\alpha$ corresponds to the map
$$\textstyle \iota^*: \mathrm{Hom}_A(\prod_i M_i, N) \to \mathrm{Hom}_A(\bigoplus_i M_i,N)$$
induced by the inclusion $\iota : \bigoplus_i M_i \hookrightarrow \prod_i M_i$. So the [Yoneda Lemma](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Yoneda+lemma) tells us that $\alpha$ is an isomorphism for all $N$ if and only if $\iota$ is an isomorphism, which is wrong when $M_i \neq 0$ for infinitely many indices $i$.

For a specific counterexample (you find this by applying the Yoneda proof), take $N = \bigoplus_i M_i$, then $(\iota_i)_i$ will (usually) not be in the image of $\alpha$.

Similarly, there is a natural homomorphism
$$\textstyle \beta :\mathrm{Hom}_A (M, \bigoplus_i N_i) \to\prod_i \mathrm{Hom}_A(M, N_i),\quad f \mapsto (p_i \circ f)_i,$$
which is injective, but it has no reason to be surjective, since it corresponds to
$$\textstyle \iota_* : \mathrm{Hom}_A (M, \bigoplus_i N_i) \to \mathrm{Hom}_A(M, \prod_i N_i)$$
for the inclusion $\iota$ above, and again the Yoneda Lemma tells us that this is an isomorphism of all $N$ if and only if $\iota$ is an isomorphism.

For a specific counterexample, take $M = \prod_i N_i$, then $(p_i)_i$ will (usually) not be in the image of $\beta$.